# Use GitHub pages on multiple repositories when one has a custom CNAME already?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a GitHub repository set up to host a small static site. The repository that hosts this is in the following format:

```
username.github.io
```

This repository is setup to use a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) and has a CNAME file to do so properly. This repository works exactly as expected.

Now I want to set up a [project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) and utilize the `gh-pages` branch for a different repository. When I do this, though, the CNAME in the first repository seems to apply and I am redirected to `example.com/REPOSITORYNAME` instead of using the expected `username.github.io/projectname` associated with this separate repository.

---

How can I continue to use the `username.github.io` repository with a custom domain *and* the `gh-pages` branch on a different repository without redirecting the `gh-pages` repository to the custom domain defined in the first repository?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to rename your `username.github.io` repository to something else, so it is no longer considered to be your special "user/organization pages" repository. It can continue using the custom domain it's already on (just make sure the `CNAME` file in the repository correctly points to your `example.com` custom domain). Then, your projects pages should start using `username.github.io` instead of the custom `example.com`.